# How can I stop gvim opening dialogs?

Tags: vim, dialog, config

I've managed to get gvim pretty close to console vim in feel, no scrollbars, no toolbars etc. However, whenever it needs to prompt me, rather than doing it below the status line it likes to open up a gui dialog. This dialog is annoying, it often appears on the wrong monitor, sometimes i miss it, and its extra keypresses/clicks to dismiss it.

Apparently I can disable simple choice dialogs using the 'c' flag for guioptions, but it doesnt seem to work for me. Perhaps my test dialogs are not considered 'simple'.

```
set guioptions+=lrbmTLce
set guioptions-=lrbmTLce
```

I'm testing against the dialog that can come up about swap files (read only, recover, edit anyway etc) and the dialog about the file changing outside of the vim instance.

Comment: When exactly does it open a dialog?

Comment: for example, when a file has changed externally to the editor, it loads a dialog to ask to reload the file. I'm aware of autoreload, but I dont wish to use it as sometimes the answer is no.

Comment: I have only guioptions=aem and don't get any dialogs. Just tried your example (changing file from outside) and still nothing.

Comment: do you still get prompted by vim about the file reload? ie within the vim window?

Comment: My mistake, it seems it still does that (must've missed it the first time). Peter below gave the correct answer. If your guioptions are 'lrbmTLce', you needn't do nothing. If not, just add "set guioptions+=c" to get it to display the text variant instead of the dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peter Rincker was in fact correct, however I found I was having some issues with whether or not things were being set in the guioptions set. The below config works to make GVim behave exactly as console vim, including disabling dialogs, console tabs, no menu's or scrollbars etc. I'm sure theres a more concise option so I'm putting this here as an answer and hoping someone comes back with the 'correct' method.

```
set guioptions+=lrbmTLce
set guioptions-=lrbmTLce
set guioptions+=c
```

Comment: Joshua, the += operator in Vim is an "add to" operator, and the -= is the "take away" operator, so what you basically got up there is equal to set guioptions=c

Comment: Well yes, i realise that. But a) you're not accounting for default values of things, and b) as far as I can find from googling, sometimes just setting -= on say, l, doesnt stick, and you have to turn it on and then off again to get the desired effect. hence the clunky syntax. Lastly, I ran into some issues with just not subtracting c in line 2. I believe this is due to how vim handles numerals/strings/flags with the -= += syntax, and I'm unsure as to whether the guioptions are considered a string or a set of flags, and differing behaviour between them.

Comment: "default values of things"? What have they got to do with anything? Guioptions are pretty much ... set and release. What issues have you ran into?

Comment: Joshua, where are you setting your 'guioptions'? Are you setting them in your vimrc or gvimrc? 'guioptions' should be set in your gvimrc. See `:h gvimrc` for more.

Comment: @PeterRincker - gvimrc is optional. You *could* set it in gvimrc, but if you set it in vimrc, it will get loaded regardless. So it doesn't really matter, and (by careful organization) you'll have one less file to manage.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following in my .gvimrc

```
set guioptions=c
```

Comment: I don't have that in my  guioptions ... still doesn't open any dialogs :/

Answer (score 1):

A small tip: I sometimes have a logfile open but I already have the portion I want from it so I don't want it to reload but I also don't want to close it in case I need something more, plus if I reload or close and reopen again the same data could be hard to find or it could have been rolled out. The popups are just a nuisance.

In this case a simple solution is to `:file anything`, the buffer is then renamed and so GVim won't look for changes in the original file anymore.